# Login/Registration using scala

Tags: html, scala, authentication, registration

Just wondering if when creating a login/registration web page using scala is very similar when doing with PHP/HTML which I have used in the past. I've just decided to start learning scala and am a total beginner with no clue. With PHP/HTML, I would use a form, 'POST' method and then the appropriate my_sqli prepared statement insertion and selections. Is it similar or very different in terms of overall methods and way about going with it (obviously excluding the minor differences in syntax). How and in what ways is it different or similar? thnx

Comment: It's nothing really to do with Scala and everything to do with the web framework you're using And that would be covered in its documentation

Answer (score 0):

Scala is totally different from PHP. Finding connections between them is really hard. I would say that Scala is better in every way but bashing PHP is just too easy nowadays.

I would suggest you to give a look at [Scalatra](http://scalatra.org/), arguably the most mature among simple web frameworks in Scala. Every framework works differently but you can get an idea of how you think and write code in Scala giving a look at Scalatra examples.

Also, if you never worked on a JVM, it will take a while before being able to properly develop logic in your code. There are many things to learn about the environment (and obviously about the language too) before being able to develop a web app. My suggestion is to first spend some time studying the language and only then begin approaching web development. If you need a language that you can pick up and start writing code, Scala is not the right choice.